# Delete the value in the input form with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

The following code themselves

```
<Input type = "radio"> <Input type = "text" name = "nominal" value = "1000">
```

I want to remove the value of the input form with radio buttons, how?

Please help me

Thank

Comment: Like resetting the form?

Comment: Yes, really like that
Can you help me ?

Comment: Why do you have a single radio button? They're supposed to be used in groups.

Comment: I need to reset a single data one by one

Comment: So why not use normal button elements? If the user clicks a radio button it will become checked, but then they could type into the input again, so then the radio button that means "reset" is already checked but the input is not empty. This sounds very confusing for users. In any case, please [edit] your question to show a bit more of your HTML, at least two or three fields for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#radio').change(function(){
            $('#nominal').val('');
        });  
        });
    </script>

    <div>
      <input id="radio" type= "radio"> 
      <input id="nominal" type= "text" name="nominal" value="1000">
    </div>
```

Comment: But what about after uncheck filled again?

Comment: Change java script like this 
         $('#radio').change(function() {
           if($('#radio').is(':checked')) {
            $('#nominal').val(''); 
           } else {
            $('#nominal').val(1000); 
           }
         });

Comment: probably you can not unchecked if you are using single radio button

Comment: So what's the solution? Mr. Richardson

Comment: you can use check box instead radio

Comment: check my 2nd answer

Comment: Yes it's okay, if I can use the same javascript, or use other functions?

Comment: you can use same but aware about attribute id, In my 2nd answer i changed id <input id="checkbox" type= "checkbox"> for check box, so little change in javascript

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using checkbox**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#checkbox').change(function() {
                if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#nominal').val('');  
                } else {
                    $('#nominal').val(1000);    
                }
        });  
    });
</script>

<div>
  <input id="checkbox" type= "checkbox"> 
  <input id="nominal" type= "text" name="nominal" value="1000">
</div>
```

Comment: how when uncheck the return value, not the value determined?
Not like this: $ ('# nominal'). Val (1000);

Comment: So what value you want to replace?